# What seems the problem with trying to import plugin in capacitor here is my code

Tags: reactjs, capacitor

I'm using capacitor to build mobile application and I need to add popup in my app and I'm having trouble with it Becouse it's my first time using it

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Alert } = Plugins;

export async function ShowPopup() {
  const result = await Alert.show({
    title: 'Location permission required',
    message: 'Please allow the app to access your location',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel'
      },
      {
        text: 'OK'
      }
    ]
  });
  console.log('User clicked ' + result);
}
```

I got following problems

- `Plugins` is deprecated
- `Alert.show()` throws

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show')

This is where I'm calling this ShowPopup

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import { ShowPopup } from "./popup";
import { Geolocation } from '@capacitor/geolocation';
import im from "../images/myloc.png"
// import Loading from './loadinf';
function Map() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosition = async () => {
      try {
        const { coords } = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
        setPosition({ lat: coords.latitude, lng: coords.longitude });
      } catch (error) {
      }
    };
    getPosition();
  }, []);

  if (!position) {
    return <ShowPopup/>;
  }

  const myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: im,
    iconSize: [38, 38],
    iconAnchor: [19, 38],
    popupAnchor: [0, -38],
  });

  return (
    <MapContainer center={[position.lat, position.lng]} zoom={15} style={{ height: '400px' }}>
      <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
      <Marker position={[position.lat, position.lng]} icon={myIcon}>
        <Popup>
          your current position {position.lat}, {position.lng}
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}

export default Map
```

@csaar

Comment: Could you pls provide us the code snippet calling`ShowPopup`.

Comment: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/dialog

Comment: @csaar that the update code

Comment: There are some conceptual problems. I mean `Alert.show` is not a functional component so you can't place it like this `<ShowPopup />`. Call it for instance in your useEffect-hook if the position can't get determined.